# The Ionization of Water

Tags: equilibrium

When we put $\ce{HCl}$ in a container of water and let's say that the concentration we put is $10^6$ molar. Let me understand this calculation:

$[\ce{OH-}]=x$
$[\ce{H+}]=10^6+x$
$x(10^6+x)=10^{-14}$

The $[\ce{OH}]$ is $x$, but what about the $[\ce{H+}]=10^6+x$ why not $10^6-x$? Because the quantity of the $[\ce{H+}]$ does not increases after we add the $\ce{HCl}$ but decreases. So why $+x$ and not $-x$?

Comment: 10^6 is absurd, almost to the point of being offensive.

Comment: what is absurd about it? I have a question with 2.19×10^−7  how is that better?

Comment: Being physically possible is a big difference

Comment: "the quantity of the [H+] does not increases" you probably meant the quantity of H+ released by water...

Comment: Sorry but why a concentration of 10^-6 is physically impossible while 10^-7 is?

Comment: Do you mean $10^6$ or $10^-6$?

Comment: sorry now I saw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the reaction,
$$\ce{HCl -> H+ + Cl-}$$

Assuming the initial $\ce{[HCl]}$ is $\pu{C M}$, after reaction takes place, we have $\ce{[H+]}$ as $\pu{C M}$.

Also its an aqueous solution. Hence we have to consider the following equilibrium:
$$\ce{ H2O <=> H+ + OH- }$$
Let initial $\ce{[H2O]}$ be $\ce{a M}$. At equilibrium, we have $\ce{[H+]} = \ce{x M}$. Since we have more $\ce{H+}$ from the ionization of water, therefore $\ce{[H+]_{net}}$ = $\ce{C +x M}$ and not $\ce{C-x M}$

**Note**: If $C \geq \mathrm{10^{-6}~M}$, $\ce{[H+]}$ coming from $\ce{H2O}$, ie. $x$, can be neglected w.r.t $C$ unless and until you’re a rigid perfectionist.

Comment: How does this answer the question: " what about the $[\ce{H+}]=10^6+x$ why not $10^6−x$?"

Comment: I have shown its plus and not minus. Haven’t I?

Comment: You have. But you haven't explained why $10^6-x$ is invalid.

Comment: We have $\ce{[H+]}$ to be increasing and hence the ‘plus sign’. I don’t get why ‘minus sign’ comes into picture. Wait, is the OP relating anything to common ion effect?

Comment: "I  don’t get why ‘minus sign’ comes into picture" I know. I also agree with you completely. But, the OP doesn't. And this answer needs to explain the OP so... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your whole question is so muddled that it is difficult to know where to begin.

> When we put HCl in a container of water and let's say that the concentration we put is $10^6$ molar.

$10^6$ molar HCl is totally absurd. The most concentrated HCl solutions will be around 12 molar. HCl is a gas at room temperature and pressure. To solidify HCl you must cool the gas to −114.22 °C. HCl has a molecular mass of 36.46 g/mol, thus neglecting any water, $10^6$ molar HCl would have $10^6$ moles of HCl in a liter volume, or a mass of 36460 kilograms per liter. Gold is only 19.30 kilograms per liter.

The other thing is that HCl ionizes in water according to the reaction

$\ce{HCl + H2O -> H3O^+ + Cl^-}$

Since pure water is only about 56 molar, there isn't nearly enough water to ionize $10^6$ moles of HCl.

**Let's talk about something more reasonable, 1.0 molar HCl.**

We can assume that all the HCl ionizes then the $\ce{[H^+]= 1.0 molar}$.

Since

$\ce{[H^+][OH^-] = } 10^{-14}$

$\ce{[OH^-] = } \dfrac{10^{-14}}{\ce{[H^+]}} =  \dfrac{10^{-14}}{1.0} = 1.0\times10^{-14}$

Now there is an assumption here about significant figures. So when we note that the HCl is 1.0 molar, we mean +/- 0.05 moles, or two significant figures. Very, very few chemistry experiments have results good to 4 significant figures.

In reality the starting pure water had $1.0\times10^{-7}$ molar $\ce{[H^+]}$ and $1.0\times10^{-7}$ molar $\ce{[OH^-]}$. Since the final solution had $1.0\times10^{-14}$ molar $\ce{[OH^-]}$, then the added HCl obviously reacted with about $1.0\times10^{-7}$ moles of $\ce{[OH^-]}$. But this amount is so small compared to the 1.0 moles of $\ce{[H^+]}$ that it is insignificant.